# Wierd stuff happens when overloading operator<< with a class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend, ostream

Here's the functionality I am expecting to achieve:

```
darray<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(3);
std::cout << a << std::endl; // displays: {1, 2, 3}
```

My implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class darray
{
private:
    long m_capacity;
    long m_size;
    T* m_data;
    void resize();

public:
    // constructors & destructors
    darray();

    // operations
    void push_back(T);
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    template<typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, U const& ar);
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& darray<T>::print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << "{ ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            os << m_data[i] << ", ";
            if ( i == m_size - 1 )
                os << m_data[i];
        }
        os << " }\n";
        return arr;
}

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, U const& obj)
{
    return obj.print(os);
}
```

produces an error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const char [66]’)
```

But, when I change the parameter of operator<< to accept a `darray<U>` instead , it works fine:

```
template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, darray<U> const& obj)
{
    return obj.print(os);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Update:

I also tried doing this, changing the parameter to `darray<U>` type in the definition and the implementation, but it still produces the same error:

```
template <typename T>
class darray
{
private:
    long m_capacity;
    long m_size;
    T* m_data;
    void resize();

public:
    // constructors & destructors
    darray();

    // operations
    void push_back(T);
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    template<typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, darray<U> const& ar);
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& darray<T>::print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << "{ ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            os << m_data[i] << ", ";
            if ( i == m_size - 1 )
                os << m_data[i];
        }
        os << " }\n";
        return os;
}

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, darray<U> const& obj)
{
    return obj.print(os);
}
```

Comment: Your defined template for `<<` takes a `U` parameter that is a potential match for a `const char*`  or `const char[]` argument, thus conflicting with the one provided by the standard library.

Comment: `std::ostream& arr` is a misleading name. You should use this parameter in the `print` function, instead of `std::cout`.

Comment: You are missing the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: The code uses `std::cout` where is should be using `os`.

Comment: @AdrianMole It doesn't work as well if I defined << in the class definition like this: `template<typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, darr<U> const& ar);`

Comment: @Zaki yes, it was a comment about something odd looking in your code, not an answer for your problem.

Comment: @mch I updated the code in the question, replaced `std::cout` with `os` still produces same error

Comment: @ÖöTiib It points to the line where i implemented the function, this: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, U const& obj)`

Comment: @Eljay I updated the code, but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Zaki I can't reproduce it <http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95870b5314468d93> your posted example does not have the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error problem with the code you've posted.  Can you provide a [mcve] that actually reproduces the problem, rather than a code snippet?  I suspect you have a bug in the code not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend functions in template classes have to be defined inside the class declaration. This is the only way I have found to have the friend function to correctly accept an instance of the templated class *with the expected template*.

So here I would write:

```
...
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, darray<T> const& ar) {
    ar.print(os);
    return os;
}
...
```

But beware: your class contains a raw pointer to allocated memory which is probably deleted in the class destructor. Per the [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/3545273), you must explicitely declare (or delete) the copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: No, nothing to do with the friend class. As mentioned in the question, it also works fine if you just define the `operator <<` function as a non-friend and non-member function outside the class. There's actually no need for a friend class, since the `operator <<` function doesn't try to access any non-public members of the class.

Comment: @ZiggyZhang: I assumed that OP declared the operator as friend because in a later version of their code, it could use non public members...

Comment: You're right. But I still have two questions: 1. If the function `template <typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, U const& ar)` defines in the class, it does work fine. But why? 2. Since operator<< is a friend function, independent of the class, sometimes I want to use it for other classes, but the problem comes again, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your `darray<T>::print` function, if you change

```cpp
os << m_data[i] << ", ";
```

to

```cpp
os << m_data[i];
os << ", ";
```

then the compiler doesn't complain and it works fine. I don't know why.